# Mixed strategies and expected payoff

Tags: game-theory

Two players call the number 1,2 or 3. If the sum of the named numbers does not exceed 4, then everyone gets what he asked for. If the sum is strictly greater than 4, everyone gets 0.

Let p1,p2,p3​ be the mixed strategy of the second player.
What is the expected payoff of the first player from applying the pure strategy that player always calls 1

Could someone check my solution?

My solution is p1*p1 since then he will get 1.

Comment: We don't know what "the pure strategy [1]" means.  Do you just mean that player one always calls $1$?

Comment: @lulu: yes,  player one always calls 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you ask questions, the title of the question should state what the question is about, but this title is too unspecific.

Comment: I would say that the expected pay off of player $1$ is $p_1+p_2+p_3$, since the payoffs of player 1 are always 1 (at alternative 1).

Comment: @callculus42: thank you for your respond. If  the first player is applying the pure strategy that player always calls 2 then his pay of is p2 + p3, right?

Comment: @AntonS For the second alternative I have an expected value of  $2p_1+2p_2$ // "**everyone gets what he asked for**" That means, for the second alternative a player gets always $2$, if the sum does not exceed $4$

Comment: @callculus42: I could not get the idea how to solve it. Do you use tables?

Comment: @AntonS Yes, I've made a payoff table with the 3 alternatives for each player.

Comment: @callculus42: could you please show me your payoff table? I would like to learn it better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AntonS Without  any claim to correctness I have $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline   P_1/P_2&1&2&3 \\ \hline 1&1/1&1/2&1/3 \\ \hline 2&2/1&2/2 &0/0 \\ \hline 3&3/1&0/0&0/0 \\ \hline \end{array}$

Comment: So there are 3 pure strategy Nash equilibria (1,3), (2,2) and (3,1).  There is also a mixed strategy equilibrium where both players play $p_1=\frac 13, p_2 = \frac 16, p_3=\frac 12$. In that case both players get an expected payoff of 1. (Assuming players are risk neutral.)

Comment: @callculus42: thank you very much

Comment: @3rdMoment: thank you very much. Could you please  recommend me some good books or web resources on the Game Theory?